# Why am I getting :Error : "HTTP request Response Assertion:Test failed:text expected to contain /302/"

Tags: jmeter

[08 nov 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk5m0.png)[08 nov 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kwVi.png)[08 nov 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQskt.png)[08 nov 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcX1j.png)[08 nov 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZuKZ.png)
[08 nov 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5hu4.png)

Why am I getting :

> HTTP request Response Assertion:Test failed:text expected to contain /302/" error in "Assertion Results"

Comment: This is not clear! Do you want to add HTTP response assertion and check the response status code? Or looking for a way to check response body?

Comment: I am sorry but I am still getting the errors :( @UBIKLOADPACK -  Thanks

Comment: Can you show what you modified ? and also an overview of where assertion is located.

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK please see images                                                      [08 nov 1][1]
[08 nov 2][2]

Comment: Show view result tree and click on one failing sample and show the 3 tabs

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK : Done ,Thanks

Comment: Added screenshots @UBIKLOADPACK .. Thank you

Comment: I removed the response code 302 and now the HTTP requests are showing as passed. @UBIKLOADPACK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you didn't check in your assertion the correct "Field to Test", you need to check Response Code not Text Response:

[image: Response Assertion wit]

Also your assertion is failing because you don’t get a 302(redirect) but a 200 (success) .
So unless you really only want 302, just remove this assertion as bu default JMeter will mark Sample as failed if response code is strictly higher than 399

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are getting this message because your [HTTP response body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages#Body_2) doesn't `contain` the search pattern of `302`.

Also be aware that `Contains` assumes a [Perl-compatible regular expression](https://www.pcre.org/) as an input, so double check your pattern, most probably you should switch to `Substring` option. See [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) and [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) articles for more details.

And finally don't use `google.com` website for load testing practice, Google has intelligent mechanisms of [DDoS attacks](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/D/DDoS_attack.html) protection so your IP address can simply be blacklisted. Use either your local intranet resources or special dedicated sites like http://newtours.demoaut.com/ or http://blazedemo.com/ for your experiments.